# How to get 'Query string parameters' from a http Get url

Tags: angular

I am calling an API using Get method, I want to just get the 'Query string parameters' which has been appended from backend. For example `https://api.npms.io/v2/search?q=scope:angular&lang='fr''`. From this API `lang='fr'` has been appended from backend. I need to get the last 'query parameters' `lang='fr'`.

### app.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
    
@Component({ selector: 'app', templateUrl: 'app.component.html' })
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    totalAngularPackages;
    
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }
    
    ngOnInit() {      
        // Simple GET request with response type <any>
        this.http.get<any>('https://api.npms.io/v2/search?q=scope:angular&lang='fr'').subscribe(data => {
            this.totalAngularPackages = data.total;
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: "https://api.npms.io/v2/search?q=scope:angular&lang='fr'" from this url last parameter

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply extract the search parameter from the URL by:

- creating an URL object from the string
- extracting the search parameters
- finally get the parameter you want

```js
const url = new URL("https://api.npms.io/v2/search?q=scope:angular&lang='fr'");
const params = new URLSearchParams(url.search);

console.log(params.get('q'));
console.log(params.get('lang'));
```

See also:

- [MDN: URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL)
- [MDN: URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)

---

Keep in mind that `'https://api.npms.io/v2/search?q=scope:angular&lang='fr''` is an invalid string. Either escape the single quotes or use double quotes:

```
const url = 'https://api.npms.io/v2/search?q=scope:angular&lang=\'fr\'';
const url = "https://api.npms.io/v2/search?q=scope:angular&lang='fr'";
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but how to get this full URL in angular  https://api.npms.io/v2/search?q=scope:angular&lang='fr'  , Since  'https://api.npms.io/v2/search?q=scope:angular ' coming from API, passing different request but the last request &lang='fr' appending from backend

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand, what you mean. You're receiving the URL from another API call? You have to add that code to the question a s well. Where exactly is the `lang` parameter added? Maybe you have to explain your problem more detailed.

Comment: I am doing the API call with the same URL https://api.npms.io/v2/search?q=scope:angular&lang='fr'  by passing the first request q=scope:angular but the last request is getting appended by backend team &lang='fr' , so I need to get the last request lang='fr' which is appended by backend